# Exceeding Facebook API Rate Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests, rate-limiting

How can I tell if my Facebook app is exceeding the rate limit, other than the obvious blocked API calls? What is the error message that is recieved? Does it show in the app insights?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does show in insights. You can go to insights > developer > activity & errors